# How do you submit to 2 forms at the same time, one form in a different directory?

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a few login pages in iframes that I'd like to use only one form to post login credentials, to the various forms that use the same username and password.

`function myform(){document.form1.submit();}`<--works

`function myform(){/path/to/other_form/login.php.document.form2.submit();}`<--doesn't work

I have done something similar to this when all the forms were within the same php page, but not in iframes, and in different folders on the server.

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thank you.

**Form**

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="thisform.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="act" value="login">
  <table ...
     <input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>
     <input name="password" type="password" id="password"/>
     <a href="javascript:myform()"/>Login</a></td>
      .../table>
</form>
```

**php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
include("config.php");
include('editor.php');

if(isset($_REQUEST["act"])) {
if ($_REQUEST["act"]=='logout') {
        $_SESSION["BLOgLogin"] = "";
        unset($_SESSION["BLOgLogin"]);
} elseif ($_REQUEST["act"]=='login') {
if ($_REQUEST["username"] == $CONFIG["admin_user"] and $_REQUEST["password"] ==     $CONFIG["admin_pass"]) {
    $md_sum=md5($CONFIG["admin_user"].$CONFIG["admin_pass"]);
    $sess_id=$md_sum.strtotime("+1 hour");
    $_SESSION["BLOgLogin"] = $sess_id;      
    $_REQUEST["act"]='posts';
} else {
    $message = 'Incorrect login details.';
}
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: Both javascript and html is clientside, what made you think this would work. Stop using iframes and ob_start/ob_get_contents() the page instead, if its just a form you could also just include it.

Comment: The problem you've run into is one of the many many reasons why (i)frames are bad and should be avoided.  I'd recommend that you rethink your page and try to figure out how to do it without any frames

Comment: How would you suggest going about this then. This is the scenario; Lets say there is a blog, a calendar, and something else to be updated, located in separate directories. So what I want is to just log in once, instead of updating one, then logging into the next and so on..They're not going to be all open at the same time.

Comment: You need some sort of server side persistence mechanism then, such as PHP cookies

Comment: Can you add the html form in your sample code? And what are the 2 forms that you need to submit simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can't technically submit a form to two pages. The web uses a request/response model, so you can't submit two requests, or get back two responses. You can sort of fake this however. What you need to do is create one form with all the fields for both of the forms you want to submit. Then, submit your form to a custom page that uses cURL to perform the individual requests to each form, and then consolidate them back into one response. Here's the cURL docs: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php